# Unusual usage of 勝 （勝たしてくれ？）

Tags: grammar, verbs

I was reading a comic and came across the following usage of 勝 which confused me.

> この試合でオレを三橋に勝たしてくれ！

I know what it means (Help me beat Mihashi in this game), but I'm not sure about how to parse "勝たしてくれ". "くれ" looks like it comes from "くれる", and I want to say that "して" is the connective form of "する", yet I've been completely unable to find a noun or suru-verb "勝た" in any of my dictionaries. The other possibility I considered was "勝たして" came from a verb "勝たす", but once again I couldn't find any such verb. What's going on here?

Comment: On the first page of search results for 勝たす, I find [this Wiktionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8B%9D%E3%81%A4). Where did you look for 勝たす? (Conventional dictionaries usually don't list all inflections of a verb. I doubt OED has an entry for "to let so. win" or "won".)

Comment: I searched on Jisho and on the Midori app on my phone, without any relevant results. Edit: Also, the conjugation table for Midori only lists the "standard" form, kataseru.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`勝たす` is a rougher variant of `勝たせる` - the causative form of `勝つ`. So it would be something like "[Please] let me defeat Mihashi".

Answer (score 4):

「[勝]{か}たしてくれ」 is only the colloquial form of 「勝たせてくれ」.

「勝たせ」　is the [連用形]{れんようけい} (continuative form) of the causative verb 「勝たせる = "to let win" or "to make win"」.  Needless to say, 「勝たせる」 consists of the verb 「勝つ = "to win"」 and the auxiliary verb 「せる = "to cause to"」.

「て」 is a connective particle.

「くれ」　is the [命令形]{めいれいけい} (imperative form)　of the verb 「くれる」

「(Person)　+ に + 勝たしてくれ」 = "Let me beat/defeat (Person)."

Other examples of the colloquial せ-to-し change:

「見して = "Show me."」、「行かして = "Let me go."」、「やらして = "Let me do it for ya"」, etc.

Comment: I had written up an answer like this, but was unsure because Wiktionary lists 勝たす as a variant causative form and the other answer claims that 勝たす is a "rougher variant". I thought that 勝たして was just the result of a sound change せ to し, but realised that I don't know any formal rule for forming the causative form.

Comment: @Earthliŋ: `...formal rule for forming the causative form`.  +10 alliteration points.